# почтовый клиент на сайте для gmail

Tags: gmail, phpmailer, imap, google-services

Возникла потребность организовать на сайте почтовый клиент, связанный с gmail. Перед этим было реализовано такое при помощи IMAP и phpMailer. Теперь же нужно сделать так чтобы пользователь мог синхронизировать , получать и отправлять письма через кнопку "войти с Google", проблема в том, что по новой документации от гугл, не получается подключаться к ящику gmail, выдает сообщение, что пользователь не авторизован, хотя при этом данные пользователя (имя, почту) отдает, но не отдает токен. Уже мозг себе сломал. Я понимаю, что это как то связано с тем, что в сервисах гугла приложение зарегистрировано на одного пользователя со своим сервисным ключем, и вот тут возник вопрос - вообще можно ли такое организовать? Чтобы пользователи входили со своими учетками гугла и подключались к своей почте?

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы понять как подключить почтовый ящик Gmail вам нужно почитать документацию о почтовом сервере Gmail. Для подключения к почтовому серверу Gmail необходима O2Auth авторизацию, если авторизироватся через неё, то ваш клиент получает статус "доверенного" приложения и получает возможность подключения к почтовому серверу от Google.